# closing modal on window vanilla js

Tags: javascript, css

I've been trying to figure out how to close the modal I made by a window click but have no success. My modal is activated by adding a class and removing the 'show-modal' class. So I created the window event listener and seems like whenever I press the "a" tag in my HTML, it also considers that click as part of the window so the modal won't even open.

However, once I remove the window event listener, the modal is working fine; but the modal does not close unless I hit the "closeModal" button.

Is there something I am doing wrong or improve on? I tried googling around but their idea is different than mine.

I know I can do this using React & Boostrap but I am also trying to learn the vanilla JS way so I want to do this right!

```
const contact = document.querySelector('.contact');
const modal = document.querySelector('.modal');
const closeModal = document.querySelector('.closeBtn');

contact.addEventListener('click', showModal);
closeModal.addEventListener('click', modalClose);
window.addEventListener('click', modalClose);

function showModal(){
    modal.classList.add('show-modal');
    console.log('clicked')
}

function modalClose(){
    modal.classList.remove('show-modal');
    console.log('closed')
}
```

Comment: What did you google?

Comment: @FSDford for example this came up https://techstacker.com/close-modal-click-outside-vanilla-javascript/.. does not cure my issue nor the W3schools example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to get around this would be to add an "underlay" to the modal and listen for clicks on that instead of the window element.

Also I like to add the modal open class to the `body` so then it's easy to adjust styling on both the modal and modal underlay.

```js
document.querySelector('button#open').addEventListener('click', e => {
  document.body.classList.add('show-modal')
})

document.querySelector('button#close').addEventListener('click', e => {
  document.body.classList.remove('show-modal')
})

document.querySelector('.underlay').addEventListener('click', e => {
  document.body.classList.remove('show-modal')
})
```

```css
.modal {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: white;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.underlay {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.show-modal .modal {
  display: block;
}

.show-modal .underlay {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<button id="open">Open Modal</button>
<div class="underlay"></div>
<div class="modal">
  <button id="close">Close Modal</button>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the idea, I actually made the .modal class as my overlay so I just added an event listener to it whenver the modal pops up.. the overlay is also behind it so that becomes the hedge to click on to unapply the class.

Answer (score 0):

You can use event.stopPropagation() to avoid event propagation, try this:

```js
function showModal(){
    event.stopPropagation();
    modal.classList.add('show-modal');
    console.log('clicked')
}
```

Comment: I like the idea; the previous user did have a good way of showcasing the logic since I am building out my portfolio landing page to connect to other projects. BUT no effort is wasted on your end, This will be a great advanced shortcut for the in the future. Thank you, @sonEtLumiere